# Can I setup Grails to auto-compile without invoking run-app?

Tags: tomcat, grails

I need to be able to run Grails in the same tomcat container as some other servlets I have running. So I'd like to hook up tomcat to run off of my grails web-app directory or something, and have grails auto-compile code changes as if I were running `run-app`. But I since I want to use tomcat for development, I don't want to also be running `run-app` the whole time. How can I have grails auto-compile my code without `run-app`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably achieve what you want if you configure the generated war file destination to point at your tomcats webapps folder and tell grails to export an already exploded war. Then all you need to do is to call `grails war` and your project will be recompiled. Sorry for the short answer but I'm typing from my cell phone right now....

Comment: The onerousness to type "grails war" each time I change my source is sort of the whole point I wanted to set up "auto-compile"

Comment: but wouldn't it be a complete overhead to "auto-compile" your project everytime the source changed? especially if your project gets bigger and bigger?

Comment: no... my macbook takes about 5 seconds to compile 500 source files. you're trying to answer a question I didn't ask.

Comment: no, I'm trying to understand what benefits are achievable through such an "auto-compile" function... but I'm sorry if I'm annoying you... I use IntelliJ IDEA 12.1 on Windows 7 which has such an "auto-compile" feature, but this only takes effect once I started the project through `run-app`. after I made significant changes to my code and all runs well I compile a war directly to the standalone tomcat's webapps folder... but that's just me, I guess